# Understanding unsigned right shift

Tags: java

The [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) describes the formula for `>>>` operator.

> The value of n >>> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with
>   zero-extension, where:
>
> If n is positive, then the result is the same as that of n >> s.
>
> If n is negative and the type of the left-hand operand is int, then
>   the result is equal to that of the expression (n >> s) + (2 << ~s).
>
> If n is negative and the type of the left-hand operand is long, then
>   the result is equal to that of the expression (n >> s) + (2L << ~s).

Why does `n >>> s = (n >> s) + (2 << ~s)`, where `~s = 31 - s` for `int` and `~s = 63 - s` for long?

Comment: It's just an arithmetic way of defining shifting in zeros from the left. Try it. The +2 part cancels out the effect of the number going negative.

Comment: I suggest that you get a piece of paper and work some examples.  That will help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is negative it means that the sign bit is set.

`>>> s` means shift `s` places to the right introducing zeros into the vacated slots.

`>> s` means shift `s` places to the right introducing copies of the sign bit into the vacated slots.

E.g.

```
10111110000011111000001111100000 >>> 3 == 00010111110000011111000001111100

10111110000011111000001111100000 >>  3 == 11110111110000011111000001111100
```

Obviously if `n` is not negative, `n >> s` and `n >>> s` are the same. If `n` is negative, the difference will consist of `s` ones at the left followed by all zeros.

In other words:

```
(n >>> s) + X == n >> s        (*)
```

where `X` consists of `s` ones followed by `32 - s` zeros.

Because there are `32 - s` zeros in `X`, the right-most one in `X` occurs in the position of the one in `1 << (32 - s)`, which is equal to `2 << (31 - s)`, which is the same as `2 << ~s` (because `~s == -1 - s` and shift amounts work modulo 32 for `int`s).

Now what happens when you add `2 << ~s` to `X`? You get zero! Let's demonstrate this in the case `s == 7`. Notice that the the carry disappears off the left.

```
  11111110000000000000000000000000
+ 00000010000000000000000000000000
  ________________________________
  00000000000000000000000000000000
```

It follows that `-X == 2 << ~s`. Therefore adding `-X` to both sides of `(*)` we get

```
n >>> s == (n >> s) + (2 << ~s)
```

For `long` it's exactly the same, except that shift amounts are done modulo 64, because `long`s have 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some additional context that will help you understand pbabcdefp's answer if you don't already know the basics he assumes:

To understand bitwise operators you must think about numbers as strings of binary digits, eg. `20 = 00010100` and `-4 = 11111100` (For the sake of clarity and not having to write so many digits I will be writing all binary numbers as `byte`s; `int`s are the same but four times as long). If you are unfamiliar with binary and binary operations, [you can read more here](http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary). Note how the first digit is special: It makes numbers negative, as if it had a place value (remember elementary math, the ones/tens/hundreds places?) of the most negative number possible, so `Byte.MIN_VALUE = -128 = 1000000`, and setting any other bit to 1 always increases the number. To easily read a negative number such as `11110011`, know that `-1 = 11111111`, then read the 0s as if they were 1s in a positive number, then that number is how far away you are from -1. So `11110011 = -1 - 00001100 = -1 - 12 = -13`.

Also understand that `~s` is bitwise NOT: It takes all the digits and flips them, this is actually equivalent to `~s = -1 - s`. Eg `~5 (00000101)` is `-6 (11111010)`. Observe how my suggested method for reading negative binary numbers is simply a trick to be able to read the bitwise NOT of the number rather than the number itself, which is easier for negative numbers close to zero because those numbers have fewer `0`s than `1`s.